# How can I draw multiple real-time plots without using or blocking the main thread?

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing, real-time, pyqtgraph

How can I draw two plots which are updated in real-time using data from a program running in the main thread?

I try to use the *QApplication* class in *PyQTGraph* but the *QApplication.exec()* function blocks the main program execution nor can it be run on a thread.

Answers to these three questions might help:

1) Is there another python visualization library/API that does not need to use the main thread to draw objects but is fast enough to draw real-time plots?

2) How would one do this using Python's multiprocessing capabilities? I just learned threading so multiprocessing seems daunting. What lines of code are necessary to pass data between a main program and another processing updating graphs?

3) Will multiprocessing be fast enough to update real-time plots in one process from the main process?

Thank you very much for any help in advance.

Comment: multiprocessing is your only option. Whether or not is is fast enough depends on the data rate (of your plot data), how many points you want displayed at once, how frequently you want to update the graph and how fast your PC is. pyqtgraph has a multiprocessing support built in if I remember correctly. I think it's demonstrated within one of the examples in the examples application.

Comment: I should elaborate, multiprocessing is your only option because the Python GIL ensures only one thread runs at a time. And all Qt based graphing libraries have to draw in the main thread anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It confirms my hunch that I have to use multiprocessing. I plan on using sockets for inter process communication unless there is an easier way.

Comment: Sockets (either python raw sockets or maybe pyzmq) will work. zmq pub/sub sockets could be a good option if you don't want sockets communication to slow down the primary process. Alternatively the python multiprocessing library has a queue object that would do it. There might also be shared memory support in the same library (although your milage may vary depending on platform)

Answer (score 3):

This is PyQt specific as this is intended to be thread-safe
.
So try to start another thread with eg. openvc module to do a second plot with

```
import threading
threading.Timer(2, self.some_opencvplotfunction).start() #start every 2 sec
```

you may **not** use any pyqt features from your main application in the opencv function as this causes a runtime error

Another way is to use matplotlib and instantiate one or more subplots!
then bind your matplotlib objects into your PyQT GUI like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("Windows"))
        Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
        ui = MAIN()
        ui.setupUi(Dialog)
```

and in your main class

```
    ui.figure, ui.axis = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.6, 6.1))
    ui.canvas = FigureCanvas(ui.figure)
    scene.addWidget(ui.canvas)
```

you are allowed to add as many sublots to your gui as your cpu is able to process...

Comment: This is enlightening. Thank you.

Comment: @mago3421 if you find this useful why no upvote or marking as good answer? Be so kind, I need rep points

Comment: I'm a newbie so my updates aren't visible but I did upvote.